# Setting extents of base layers to the extents of newly added layer on the map in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, geojson, wfs, web-mapping

I am querying two layers, based on which I am adding the resultant layer (*having lesser polygons than the original one*) on map

Suppose this is the base layer,
[image]

After querying, I get this resultant layer

[image]

Which I am adding on map as.

[image]

```
// 1. map view


var myview = new ol.View({
  projection: 'EPSG:4326',
  center: [74, 28.2],
  zoom: 4,
  maxZoom: 10,
  minZoom: 1,
  smoothResolutionConstraint: true,
  showFullExtent: true,
  extent: [60, 6, 100, 40],
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'js-map',
  view: myview,
  overlays: [overlay],
});


// 2. Base layer

var india_dist_layer_source = new ol.source.TileWMS({
  url: someURL,
  params: { "LAYERS": " aasdagrometgis:INDIA_DIST_GCS", "tiled": true },
  serverType: "geoserver"
})
var india_dist_layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: india_dist_layer_source,
  opacity: 1.0,
  minZoom: 7,
  zIndex: 2,
  visible: true,
  title: "India_District_Boundary"
})

map.addLayer(india_dist_layer);

// 3. Adding Quaried layer
var geojson, featureOverlay;

$(function () {


  var btn = document.getElementById("query_btn");

  btn.addEventListener("click", function query() {


    $('#xyz').empty();
    if (geojson) {
      map.removeLayer(geojson);
    }

    if (featureOverlay) {
      featureOverlay.getSource().clear();
      map.removeLayer(featureOverlay);

    }

    var url3 = some_wfs_URL_after_querying;

    geojson = new ol.layer.Vector({
      source: new ol.source.Vector({
        url: url3,
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON({
          dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
          featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
        })
      }),
      style: style,
      visible: true,

    });


    geojson.getSource().on('addfeature', function () {
      map.getView().fit(
        geojson.getSource().getExtent(),
        {
          duration: 1590,
          size: map.getSize()
        }
      );
    });

    // map.removeLayer(india_dist_layer);

    map.addLayer(geojson);


  });

});
```

Is there any way that base layers remain active but only the content within newly added layer shows up (*as if, only the content of vector layer within the bounds of highlighted dark blue polygons appears, and the rest is masked*)?

The final output should be this

[image]

Comment: You can do it like this https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/layer-clipping-vector.html (you would need to make a single MultiPolygon feature for the districts you want to include)

Comment: @TomazicM, & @Mike I could not find ```map.addLayer();``` option in that example & background stamen layer was apparent in the background, which is not masked. Only clip layer should be present.

Comment: The Stamen layer can be removed, and replace OSM with your tile layer. Then clip that using a a single MutiPolygon created by combining the district geometries from your WFS https://codesandbox.io/s/layer-clipping-vector-forked-5vqin?file=/main.js

Comment: @Mike I tried several possibilities of creating MultiPoylgon, but none of my combinations worked. It seems `vectorContext.setStyle(style);` is crucial point to make it work. It would be very useful if you would put this into an answer.

Comment: @TomazicM The original example uses the `DrawFeature()` method which takes the same black fill style. `vectorContext.setStyle()` is only needed because I used `DrawGeometry()` instead of `DrawFeature()` to avoid creating a new feature for the MultiPolygon.

Comment: @Mike Yes, I learned that in the process of discovering methods in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_render_canvas_Immediate-CanvasImmediateRenderer.html. I still hope you'll make this into an answer.